# LARGE broken Aloe Vera

Tags: succulents, propagation

Moved my 15 year old aloe vera: pot tipped over in the back seat. It broke off almost completely from its single root.  Cut the remaining root off (was hanging by sisal type material) and the two leaves that had broken. I am going to let the stem on the base of the crown and the leaves harden off for a week or two.  Question is, can I replant the plant crown in fresh soil with or without rooting hormone and hope for the best if the crown hardened off?  Can I plant the root stem?  I'm going try to root the leaves... has anyone had success saving a huge aloe vera in pieces?  It's going into a 5 gallon terra cotta pot if I can save it...

Comment: A day or two for drying is plenty. Hormones are not needed. Every leaf reroots, but 5 gal. is overkill, since 2 is enough.